# ESLint config extended with airbnb and prettier, for a react project using typescript, jest and react-hooks

Tags: eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb, eslintrc

I'm very confused about how to setup the config file and which configs/plugins I should use.

I have a React project that uses Typescript, Jest and React hooks.

I know I need to install:

- `eslint`
- `prettier`, `eslint-config-prettier`, `eslint-plugin-prettier`
- `eslint-plugin-import`

As for the Airbnb config, I'm not sure whether I need to install:

- `eslint-config-airbnb`, `eslint-plugin-react`, `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`
  or
- `eslint-config-airbnb-base`

It doesn't seem like either of these support Typescript, so it seems I also need to install:

- `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`, `@typescript-eslint/parser`

And for Jest, I need to install:

- `eslint-plugin-jest`

I'm not sure about React hooks. Do I need to install anything additional here or do one of the other packages include support for it? I see I have the option of installing:

- `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`

Is that required?

Now, for the config file there are two areas I'm concerned with: `extends` and `plugins`.

I see that a few of these packages can be extended with `/recommended`. Should I use any of these? What should the `extends` section be? I've seen examples where it sets it as:

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb-base", "plugin:prettier/recommended"]
}
```

While I've seen other examples that use:

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier"]
}
```

And another example that uses:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "prettier/react"
  ]
}
```

What about the other Typescript, Jest and React Hooks plugins? For example, `eslint-plugin-jest` suggests adding `"plugin:jest/recommended"` to the extends. Will that conflict with any of the others? I see I could also add `"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"` and `"prettier/@typescript-eslint"`. Should they be included too?

For the `plugins` section, do I just list each `eslint-plugin-....` package that I installed?

Here's an example, please let me know how this looks:

Installed packages

```
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
@typescript-eslint/parser
eslint
eslint-config-airbnb
eslint-config-prettier
eslint-plugin-import
eslint-plugin-jest
eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y
eslint-plugin-prettier
eslint-plugin-react
eslint-plugin-react-hooks
prettier
```

Config file:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:jest/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint", 
    "import",
    "jest", 
    "jsx-a11y", 
    "react", 
    "react-hooks"
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thought I'd come back an answer this. Here's my final configuration that works:

```
module.exports = {
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:jest/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "prettier/react"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "jsx": true,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "useJSXTextNode": true
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "import", "jest", "react", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
      "error",
      {
        "allowExpressions": true,
        "allowTypedFunctionExpressions": true
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": "off",    
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": ["error", { extensions: [".jsx", ".tsx"] }],
    "react/prop-types": [0]
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could leave a `plugins` array empty.